# How to pass images to a multidimensional array in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

Mainly I am working with [`Nestjs`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) file uploading.

I want to pass images in a multidimensional array. Like this: (Based on Postman)

```
images[0][0] = image1
images[0][1] = image2
images[1][0] = image3
and so on......
```

Second problem is:

While I am going to pass it via Axios to another server it's making `Buffer` data. But I need pure file type data so that I can easily process these images.

What should be the process?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#array-of-files did you check official documentation?

Comment: Yes. I checked that. It accept one dimensional data.

Comment: As far as I know, the Node.js does not have File type data, every file is binary data, so the buffer contains the binary data of a file. If you want to process it somehow or work with it You can use `sharp` npm package.

Comment: @Ayzrian, Okay. Let me check.

Comment: Why are you looking to use a multi-dimensional array for file upload?